# Any ideas to improve my badge system?

Tags: php, database-design, doctrine-orm, badge

I'm working a badge system, so far, I've this idea:

Create a UserMeta tables to store data which will be used in criteria.

```
UserMeta
===========================
user_id | posted_comment_count | flagged_comment_count | reputation | etc.
```

i'm wondering if it's a good ideas, as if I need to add some meta to be used as a criterion, I'll need to add a column, so I think to used a serialized object, in json, or something for example.

Another table called Badge:

```
badge_id | badge_name | badge_criteria
```

Where badge criteria is a json or any other serialized format, which store an object like :

```
{
  'posted_comment_count': '>= 20',
  'flagged_comment_count': '=10',
}
```

And another table to relate users to badges (a simple association table)

I'm using Doctrine2, and I though to use Event to update UserMeta.

Any feedbacks, recommandations?

Comment: My preference would be to use a EAV pattern to store the user meta details so it's extensible. And have separate badge classes that act on the data.

Comment: @JohnP, what would be the benefit of EAV over the serialized object, in both case that's "against" the classical database design rules, moreover, EAV makes lose the database integrity, as it does with serialized object, but is far more complex to work with (wrap EAV programmaticly is harder than unserialize an object)

Comment: I meant its used to organize the UserMeta table. Specially since it allows you to add more and more criteria. It should be trivial enough to write an eav class to get related data for a user. Storing the data as json is ok. I simply meant you can have a class for each type of badge that will actually contain the code to apply it

Answer (score 3):

My database for gamification is very simple.  I have a table of "Currency," which has a single field, a name.  I have a table of "UserCurrency," which has the ID of the User, the ID of the Currency they've earned, and an integer of how much they've earned. Of course, I have a User table.

And that's it.

I use Django, so some of this might not make sense, but basically I have an event listener that listens for events on the database.  When the user does *anything* that results in a hit to the database, the event listener rolls through an array of functions, each of which contains a simple criteria in the target language for when a badge might be awarded.  If the user hits that criteria, the badge is awarded.  (A "currency" might be "number of posts," or "number of responses," or even "number of pokes."  Don't mistake it for a monetary value; it's just a tally of *whatever* it is you want to track.

It's a dead simple and completely extensible accounting mechanism for keeping score, without cluttering your database's schema with details about specific things you're tracking.  It is completely independent of any other User-tracking details, like a profile. If you want to add a new currency, something new you're going to track and correlate and award badges for, you add its name to the Currency table, a set of rules for how it's awarded, a set of rules for the thresholds at which the user receives some acknowledgement, and then it's up to you to decide how to show that to the user and what the consequences of the award are.

Also, rules can correlate.  Stack Overflow does this very (very!) well.  When you visit the site, for example, the rule triggered doesn't even count currencies, but days visited, for the "Enthusiast" badge.  Every time you get reputation, the code only updates the currency counter "legendary" by 1 if your score goes over 200, and when that currency hits 150 another trigger awards your "Legendary" badge, and so on.  De-coupling and independence are powerful tools in gamification design.

Comment: Does it work for badges that need to maintain a "state"? For example, award a badge when somebody does something for 365 days in a row. Would you change anything 12 years after your original answer?

Comment: That's a more complex scenario, but I don't see why it should be difficult to implement. That sounds more like a query on existing data.  Remember that this is only tracking user _events_ that you want to count toward some reward, not the rewards themselves.  Reasons for awarding are independent of this particular gamification scenario.